# React custom hook returns empty array when first renders

Tags: reactjs

I am new in to programming and React and I am really confused with the problem I'm facing.
I have one component which renders a catalog with drivers and I want when click on a driver to navigate in to his details page.
I have created the driver details component and I am retrieving data from one custom hook which fetches the data from the server. I'm adding additionally to this custom hook more information because the server does not provide images, that's why I choose this path.

The problem is when the Driver component first mounts and render the custom hook returns empty array and after that it returns full array with data. When I try to set the data in to react state, the state is empty and i need to double save in the vscode when first renders in order to appear some data in the screen.

Here is example code of Driver component which is the detail page of the driver.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDriversData } from "../../hooks/useDriversData";

const Driver = () => {
  const [driver, setDriver] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const driverListApiData = useDriversData();
  const { id } = useParams();

  // const driverInfo = driverListApiData.find(data => {
  //   return data.id === id
  // })


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await driverListApiData;
      setDriver(data.find((data) => data.id === id));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (driver === undefined) {
    return null;
  }

  console.log(driver);

  return (
    <div className="driver-main-container">
      <div className="listing-container">
        <img src={driver.driverProfileImg} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Driver;
```

And here is part of the custom hook. Btw the custom hook works perfectly on another components where I'm using it.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getDriversStandings } from "../services/reqester";

export const useDriversData = () => {
  const [driver, setDriver] = useState([]);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   const fetchData = async () => {
  //     const result = await getDriversStandings();
  //     setDriver(Object.values(result.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists))
  //   }
  //   fetchData()
  // }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    getDriversStandings().then((result) => {
      setDriver(Object.values(result.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists));
    });
  }, []);

  const driverList = [
    {
      id: "",
      position: "",
      points: "",
      team: "",
      racingNumber: "",
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      nationImg: "",
      driverImg: "",
    },
  ];

  const driverListApiData = [];

  driverList.forEach((driverList) => {
    driver.forEach((driverData) => {
      if (driverData.DriverStandings) {
        driverData.DriverStandings.forEach((data) => {
          if (data.Driver.driverId === "max_verstappen") {
            driverListApiData.push({
              ...driverList,
              id: data.Driver.driverId,
              position: data.position,
              points: data.points,
              team: data.Constructors[0].name,
              firstName: data.Driver.givenName,
              lastName: data.Driver.familyName,
              racingNumber:
                "https://media.formula1.com/d_default_fallback_image.png/content/dam/fom-website/2018-redesign-assets/drivers/number-logos/MAXVER01.png.transform/2col-retina/image.png",
              nationImg:
                "https://media.formula1.com/d_default_fallback_image.png/content/dam/fom-website/flags/Netherlands.jpg.transform/2col-retina/image.jpg",
              driverImg:
                "https://media.formula1.com/d_driver_fallback_image.png/content/dam/fom-website/drivers/M/MAXVER01_Max_Verstappen/maxver01.png.transform/2col-retina/image.png",
              driverProfileImg:
                "https://media.formula1.com/content/dam/fom-website/drivers/2023Drivers/verstappen.jpg.img.1024.medium.jpg/1677069646195.jpg",
              podiums: "80",
              maxPoints: "2080.5",
              grandPrixEntry: "166",
              worldChampionships: "2",
              highestPosition: "1",
              placeBirth: "Hasselt, Belgium",
            });
          } else if (data.Driver.driverId === "perez") {
            driverListApiData.push({
              ...driverList,
              id: data.Driver.driverId,
              position: data.position,
              points: data.points,
              team: data.Constructors[0].name,
              firstName: data.Driver.givenName,
              lastName: data.Driver.familyName,
              racingNumber:
                "https://media.formula1.com/d_default_fallback_image.png/content/dam/fom-website/2018-redesign-assets/drivers/number-logos/SERPER01.png.transform/2col-retina/image.png",
              nationImg:
                "https://media.formula1.com/d_default_fallback_image.png/content/dam/fom-website/flags/Mexico.jpg.transform/2col-retina/image.jpg",
              driverImg:
                "https://media.formula1.com/d_driver_fallback_image.png/content/dam/fom-website/drivers/S/SERPER01_Sergio_Perez/serper01.png.transform/2col-retina/image.png",
            });
```

I've tried to make it async function in order to wait the data to resolve but this didn't work, because I need to double save when the component first renders in order to get the data.

Comment: Did you paste all the code? I’m not seeing a return value for the `useDriversData` hook.

Comment: Show what does the `useDriversData` `return`. Also you would need to return the *setter function* so that inside the component - `Driver` - where you are calling (*/using*) this Hook would need to call this setter function to cause an update = a re-render. Can you post reproducible code: [https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new)

Comment: I've missed to copy all the code from the useDriversData.js, but basically in returns at the end the driverListApiData; 

Here is a link to the code of both files. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-hooks-kemvpm?file=/src/useDriversData.js